# I have an installed apk but i cannot find its path using usb with file explorer on mac

Tags: java, android, apk, appium

I want to run Appium on an already installed app on my Android device.

(it's a 3rd party app. Like FB or Gmail)

I want to set

```
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "../../../---");
File app = new File(appDir, "----.apk");
```

But I cannot find where is the apk installed on my device (plugged in with USB and still don't find the apk in the file explorer)

how can i easily find this apk path?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to automate an app which is already installed on your Android device, you do not need to specify an APK file at all. You capabilities should be the following:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "<your-android-activity>");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "<your-android-package>");
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://<url-to-your-appium-server>:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Capabilities `appActivity` and `appPackage` are mandatory in this case when not specifying capability `app`!

From [Appium documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities):

- Capability `appActivity`: Activity name for the Android activity you want to launch from your package. This often needs to be preceded by a . (e.g., `.MainActivity` instead of `MainActivity`).
- Capability `appPackage`: Java package of the Android app you want to run, like `com.example.android.myApp`.

Comment: I meant for an 3rd party app. not one I have written. e.g. automate FB flow

Comment: That is fine. Indeed you need to know what the name of the app package are and how they appear on your device. If you go to Settings on your device and inspect installed apps, you should be able to get this information. This post might help: http://www.42gears.com/blog/2012/05/how-to-determine-package-name-of-an-android-application-running-on-the-device/

Comment: This as well might provide more info: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name